# if else shorthand in C

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

Is the statement below a kind of shorthand? i need someone help me understand with it.

```
#define clean_errno()(errno == 0? "None": strerror(errno))
```

From the execution result, I guess it means once  I confront `clean_errno()`,if `errno ==0`, I replace `clearn_errno()` with `None`, if not, I replace `clean__errno()` with `strerror(errno)`. but I don't know how to analyse this statement logically?

Comment: You're right, that's how it is evaluated. It's the ternary conditional operator of the C language. So what's the problem then?

Comment: just replace the macro string in the context and you'll see how the logic works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is evaluated during runtime and follows the shorthand:

```
condition ? if_true : if_false
```

This shorthand is very similar to a regular `if else` statement.

However, unlike normal `if else` in C, the shorthand can be used as an expression as well as a statement. i.e.:

```
char * str = 1 ? "true" : "false";
```

... which doesn't work so well with `if else` (`char * str = if ...` probably wouldn't work).

Try it with `0 ? "true" : "false"` and test it out.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Preprocessor macros are *replaced* in their call-sites.

That means a statement like

```
printf("Error = %s\n", clean_errno());
```

will be replaced by

```
printf("Error = %s\n", (errno == 0? "None": strerror(errno)));
```

That will then at run-time print either `"None"` if `errno == 0`, otherwise print the result of `strerror(errno)`.

As for the `?:` expression itself, it is the [*conditional (a.k.a. the ternary) expression*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator), and it works similar to a `if-else`.

However, using a macro like this is not something I would recommend, as the value of `errno` is usually undefined if a function doesn't fail. You need to make sure the previous function actually *did* fail before checking `errno`, in which case it will never be zero. There are very few places where `errno` will be reset to zero unless you specifically do it beforehand and *know* that the function you call will not modify it unless there's an error.